# Avoiding implicit parameters becoming implicit conversions

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, implicits, scala-implicits

The intended output of the following code is the digit, `0`.

```
object Bad extends App {
  implicit val massTable: Map[String, Int] =
    Map("H" -> 1, "He" -> 4, "O" -> 16)

  Implementation.doWork()
}

object Implementation {
  def doWork()(implicit massTable: Map[String, Int]) = println("0".toInt)
}
```

The actual output is an exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 0
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3.apply(Map.scala:156)
at Implementation$.doWork(Main.scala:20)
at Bad$.delayedEndpoint$Bad$1(Main.scala:16)
...
```

Investigation shows that `Map` implements `apply(string): Int` causing the implicit parameter supplied to `doWork`, `massTable`, to also and unintentionally function as an implicit conversion from `String => Int`.

The result is that, the above `toInt` call is the synthetic method `toInt` for the type `Int`, rather than the `toInt` method provided by `StringOps`.

What is the best way to avoid this sort of issue and achieve the desired output?

Comment: Wrap your implicit `Map` in a case class.

Comment: This is just one of many, many reasons not to use implicit scope as a place to tuck away data.

Comment: I am with Travis here. Don't use implicit parameters to simply pass parameters to you as a DI container would do.

Comment: It's hard to convince people not to use implicit scope as configuration source when standard library and popular libraries do just that (`ExecutionContext`, `ActorMaterializer`, ...). Usually the compromise is to define implicits only for some very specific type that you own.